# C:\Python27\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, iis, iis-8

I'm trying to install a `Django` (version 1.9) application in IIS (version 8.5). I've followed several tutorials but I always get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Python27\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

I've tried to run the application in my command line and everything works fine so its some configuration that I'm missing. I've already gave my project permissions for IIS_IUSRS. I've got the following handler configurated:

```
<add name="Django Handler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python27\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ansr_bk\manage.py fcgi --pythonpath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ansr_bk\wfastcgi.py --settings ansr.settings" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
```

Do you know which configuration I'm missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: You probably shouldn't  insert script name to `pythonpath`. It is only path to your Django installation.

Comment: You need to find more about this error, the reasons for error are uncountable. Try activating the fcgi logging by putting FCGI_LOG=True and FCGI_LOG_PATH(if not specified, the project directory will be used) in your settings.py. Also set DEBUG=True in settings.py . Another possibility would be to add try, except block to manage.py and output the exception to a file manually.